# Get user group id in Joomla with PHP

Tags: php, joomla

To get the user group id in Joomla 2.5.15, I followed the documentation in [Joomla Documentation here](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object)

My code looks like this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo "<p>Your group id is {$user->gid}.</p>";
```

But this code is producing the error: Notice: Undefined property: JUser::$gid in 
Without any group id in the output.

Comment: Hi, Drupal? I'm on Joomla 2.5

Comment: In 1.6+ users can be assigned to multiple user groups, not just one, hence the old API to get a single ID is not going to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$user   = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');

foreach ($groups as $group)
{
    echo '<p>Group = ' . $group . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, I had alsto tried that one but I get: "Your group is deprecated"

Comment: @NunoNogueira you have your usertype as deprecated. See your table.

Comment: @loops yes, in the database my usertype shows deprecated and empty for all other users, but what I'm trying to get is the group_id

Comment: Hey I know this is old but how can I say "if ($groups == "1") then..."

Comment: @Mailblade inside the foreach loop, do `if ($group == 1)`

Comment: Thank you @Lodder. I wasn't sure about using quotations or not. Haha thanks for replying to this ancient thread!

Answer (score 1):

```
jimport( 'joomla.access.access' );
$groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($user_id, false);
var_dump($groups);
```

Comment: Don't just post a code block. Add some explanation or context. Otherwise your post might not be of any use to future visitors. Also your code was formatted terribly, I already edited your post this time and fixed the formatting. Be more careful in the future.

Answer (score -1):

[FROM DOCS](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object)

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(99); 
echo "<p>Your usertype is {$user->usertype} which has a group id of {$user->gid}.</p>";
```

Comment: `usertype` has been deprecated since Joomla 1.6